# VBA Prevent Charts from AutoUpdating in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, charts, user-experience

I have a button to import data into my spreadsheet. I ported the calculated values for visuals outside of the dashboard range and plotted charts linking to those values. Whenever I import new data, those values change instantly as well as the charts. Is it possible to prevent the charts from automatically updating, and move that command to a macro?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think that's possible without another layer of abstraction (i.e., creating a secondary sheet which holds a copy of the values, and link the charts to *that* sheet, or writing directly to the chart series data without linking to sheet -- which is very cumbersome to do but it is possible).

Comment: Snap! 2 seconds between us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to delay/defer updating the visuals of a chart, even if you disable calculation, the charts will refresh when its data source refreshes, but you could point your charts to a data source on a hidden sheet, and use a macro to update the values there when a button is clicked.

Let me know in the comments if you get stuck doing this, or if this is not satisfactory.

Comment: Yeah I realized this after some trial and error. A lot of the previous questions similar to mine say to turn on Manual calculation or whatever - none of that works. I ended up working around this and implementing two macros into one (which turned out nicely since it simplified my work).

Thanks for the quick replies everyone.